# Hide AvatarImage with JSQMessageViewController is causing white gaps

Tags: swift, swift2, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessageViewControllers library to implement the chat view. However, I want to hide the avatar image in the chat.

According to the following documentation. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.2.0/Protocols/JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource.html#//api/name/collectionView:avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:

I will just need to return nil in the following function.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}
```

However, after returning nil. It has white spaces for each message for the original avatar location. 
[chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCNWr.png)

How can we remove the white spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the following properties in my JSQMessageViewController subclass to remove the white spaces.

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view did load setting

`collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = .zero
 collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = .zero`

`.zero` comes form CoreGraphics CGSize